# React Native detect tap on View

Tags: react-native

I’m writing a React Native app and I want to detect tap/clicks anywhere on the screen so I put an onClick handler on my `<View>` element but it doesn’t seem to be working. Here is my render function:

```
<View style={styles.container} onClick={this.onClick}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Tap to change the background
    </Text>
</View>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: React Native is not ReactJS

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For making any element to handle touch/click events in a React-Native UI, you need to put the element inside a TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableNativeFeedback or TouchableHighlight element:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress = { this.onClick }>
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Tap to change the background
    </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i assume that you are changing the view color... try setting the color to the TouchableHighlight element via it's style.

Answer (score 30):

In React Native version > 55.3 you make check onPress events into your View if use **onStartShouldSetResponder** props.

Like example:

```
<View 
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => console.log('You click by View')}
 >

    <ScrollView 
        refreshControl={
           <RefreshControl 
               refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
               onRefresh={this.onRefresh} />
           }
      >

     <Text>Awesome</Text>

    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

In example I showed how you can get onPress event on View and not blocking other event behind them. Refresh control still work correct.

Comment: this is really helpful

Comment: Although this works, it should be kept in mind that, in case you have a `ScrollView` containing 1 or more `View` that use `onStartShouldSetResponder`, the event attached to each `View` will be dispatched on the spot and you will not be able to scroll. This is hard to notice if you are using an iOS simulator on a Mac, but you will see it when the app is deployed and running on the phone. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665408/16425431) is the correct answer

Answer (score 14):

In my case the following works fine. You can use `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd` handlers on any `View` via props, for example:

```
<View onTouchStart={() => this.doSomething()} />
```

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48754840/4791116)

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working on Android. onTouchEnd for example. iOS works tho

Comment: Nevermind, i had to add backgroundColor to the view, in my case, transparent.. and that made it work.. pretty nasty.

Comment: This works fine, but it is also fired when we click any child element. How can we stop that?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me...

```
onTouchEnd={() => alert('TAPPED')}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={()=> whateverFunc(parameter)}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
       Tap to change the background
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

So, you need to replace the 'View' component to a 'TouchableOpacity' or any other Touchable component and you also need to replace the 'onClick' prop to 'onPress'. That's all. The wrapping of a view with a TouchableWhatever component is not necessary at all.