# React Native: View onPress does not work

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a weird problem. In my react native app, if I set `onPress` event to `View` it is not triggered but if I set the same to `Text` inside `View`, it fires. What am I missing here?

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: "red", padding: 20}}>
  <Text onPress={()=> {
    console.log('works');
    }
  }>X</Text>
</View>


<View style={{backgroundColor: "red", padding: 20}} onPress={()=> {
    console.log('does not work');
    }
  }>
  <Text>X</Text>
</View>
```

Why is this so? Is this an issue with React Native? I'm using version 0.43

Answer (score 268, accepted):

You can use `TouchableOpacity` for `onPress` event. 
`View` doesn't provide `onPress` prop.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: "red", padding: 20}} onPress={()=> {
    console.log('does not work');
    }
  }>
  <Text>X</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Complete reference documentation is here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html

Comment: Can onPress work with an async function as its callback? I don't see mention of this in the official documentation.

Answer (score 39):

You can wrap the view with a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and then use `onPress` and friends like usual. Also you can still block `pointerEvents` by setting the attribute on on the child view, it even blocks pointer events on the parent `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, its interesting, this was my need on Android, I didn't test on iOS:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPressIn={this.closeDrawer}>
    <Animated.View style={[styles.drawerBackground, styleBackground]} pointerEvents={isOpen ? undefined : 'none'} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: Tested on iOS and it works just fine. Both with touchable without feedback and touchable highlight

Comment: Thanks for sharing @habed! Did the `pointerEventsNone` on the child block presses on the wrapping parent?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively you can also provide onStartShouldSetResponder to your view, like so:

```
<View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => console.log("View click")}>
  // some code here
</View>
```

Comment: Although this works, it should be kept in mind that, in case you have a `ScrollView` containing 1 or more `View` that use `onStartShouldSetResponder`, the event attached to each `View` will be dispatched on the spot and you will not be able to scroll. This is hard to notice if you are using an iOS simulator on a Mac, but you will see it when the app is deployed and running on the phone. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43665408/16425431) is the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, to achieve this. View component doesn't provide onPress as props. So you use these instead of that.

```js
<TouchableNativeFeedback
        onPress={this._onPressButton}
</TouchableNativeFeedback>

OR

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
</TouchableHighlight>

OR

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 6):

For this issue you can make use either

```
touchable(opacity,withoutfeedback,....)
```

or `Pressable` component which is currently available in react native Package like,

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>console.log("Pressed")}>
  ....
</TouchableOpacity>
```

or

```
<Pressable onPress={()=>console.log("Pressed")}>
  ....
</Pressable>
```

Answer (score 5):

onPress doesn't work on `<View>` tag use `<TouchableOpacity>` instead of View

```
<View>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 'call your function here'}>
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

2021

> If you're looking for a more extensive and future-proof way to handle touch-based input, check out the [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) API.

Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback

Answer (score 2):

A new pressable component is provided in 0.67 of react native, which can solve your problem. It runs anywhere
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx9Fe.png)

Answer (score 1):

well we can make the View have a onPress props **onStartShouldSetResponder** and **onResponderGrant**

```
<View
    onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
    onResponderGrant={() => console.log("view pressed")}
  >
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use TouchableOpacity for that purpose

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {your code here}}>
    //Your inner views here
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In View onPress will not work because onPress event is not supported in view tag.That is why it is not working but you can go to this link https://reactnative.dev/docs/view

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pressable** components which is react native core component and wrap your View or any other component in **Pressable** which don't have **onPress** prop.

Like this:

```
<Pressable onPress={()=>console.log('pressed')}>
   <View>
     <Text>Some Text</Text>
   </View>
</Pressable>
```

[Pressable Documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

Answer (score -1):

For anybody who's lookig for a solution to this, as of RN 0.63, there is a new [Pressabe](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) api. It might have rolled out a couple versions earlier but it works great for such use cases.

```
<Pressable onPress={onPressFunction}>
    <Text onPress={() => {
        console.log('works');
    }}>X</Text>
</Pressable>
```

Comment: That didn't work with me