# Basic state on react native

Tags: react-native

I new to react native, can someone explain how to change this state variable
(I got no error)

```
class Header extends Component{
   state = {
      navDoggo : ['Apartment','Services'],
      nav_id : 1
     }
   render(){
      return(
        <View style={{width : 60, height:60}} onPress ={
          () =>
         {return (this.state.navDoggo[0] = 'abcd');}
            }>
          <Text>{this.state.navDoggo[0]}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
```

my Question :
`1. Can i declare variable outside class ?`
`2. Is declaring variable without type was react-native feature ?`
`3. how to change that state object`
Sorry for my lack of knowledge for understanding documentation

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can i declare variable outside class

Yes.

> 2. Is declaring variable without type was react-native feature ?

No. This is JavaScript. React-Native is a JavaScript library.

> 3. how to change that state object

```
this.setState(previousState => (
    { oldKey: newValue }
  ))
```

Pay attention that assigning a different value to an array in your state wouldn't trigger any render as it is the same object in the state.

You must read the [documentations](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state), this is the most fundamental thing in React. Perhaps, looking at your two first questions, you should start from JavaScript.

Comment: can i use that onPress property on `<View>` tag ? or it's only for some tag only

Comment: No, View doesn't provide the onPress prop.
[Please give a look at these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665177/react-native-view-onpress-does-not-work)

Comment: if not too much can you please correct my code, i found some error.

Comment: so in this case, i need to use at least Button for event handler

Comment: `state = { navDoggo : ['Apartment','Services']  }`
`this.setState(()=>this.state.navDoggo[0] : 'test' )`
is this possible ?

Comment: I recommend starting with primitives, non-arrays values in the state. You will have problems with arrays. Read what I've wrote earlier.